# HTML Reports in JMeter - Modification

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a requirement in JMeter, While generating HTML reports using non gui mode,

1. Only corresponding controllers should get displayed and it should not display its HTTP request samplers
2. Controllers should not display randomly, It should display according to its order assigned inside the thread group (Eg: Controller 1, 2, 3)

[image]

Is there any solution for this requirement ?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote so that others can trust it ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid displaying HTTP Requests, use [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) and apply naming policy as explained [here](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/reporting-feature-in-jmeter/).

For order, by default jmeter order by label. So an option would be to use a prefix that will be use for sorting (a, b, c ... z).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't want the individual HTTP Request samplers to be displayed - put them under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) and tick `Generate parent sample` box
2. Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   ```
3. Use [__threadGroupName() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) as the Transaction Controller's label prefix

---

Example test plan outline:

[image]

Example generated APDEX table in the dashboard:

[image]